# How to use method of classes inside method of other class when argument is const reference?

Tags: c++, class, reference

I have class `mSkeleton` with some methods:

```
//mSkeleton Class
mSkeleton::mSkeleton( const double& M, const int& N){ 
mass = M;
nph = N;
}

double mSkeleton::getNph(){
  return nph;
}
...
```

And I have another class `mizer` with some methods:

```
void mizer::addMassSkeleton( const mSkeleton& mass ){
  masses.push_back( mass );
  count_external_phs += mass.getNph();
}
```

When I compile it I get the error:

```
mizer.C:46:24: error: member function 'getNph' not viable: 'this' argument has type
const mSkeleton', but function is not marked const
count_external_phs += mass.getNph();
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a const object means that you cannot call methods that can potentially change the object, so this line:

```
count_external_phs += mass.getNph();
```

cannot be called, because masses is const, and you want to modify it by doing a getNph, now I do realize that you don't actually wanna modify the object when you call getNph - but the compiler doesn't knows that.

you can modify the code and add a 'const' keyword on the method to mark it const.

```
double mSkeleton::getNph() const {
   return nph;
}
```

take also a look in [c++ const correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness)

Answer (score 3):

You need to mark getNph() method as const, like so:

```
double getNph() const; // in header file

double mSkeleton::getNph() const { ... } // in .cpp
```

const used like this means that getNph method will not change object state.

By default all methods are non-const. If you don't explicitly mark your method as const, the compiler thinks calling this method will change the object state, which you shouldn't do because you receive `mass` object as const: `void mizer::addMassSkeleton( const mSkeleton& mass ){`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to mark mizer::addMassSkeleton(...) as const method.

```
void mizer::addMassSkeleton(const mSkeleton& mass) const {
  masses.push_back( mass );
  count_external_phs += mass.getNph();
}
```

If you have a method which you declare const, all the class's methods that you use in that function must also be const, otherwise, the non-const function which is your const function may alter the object. Altering the object breaks the 'const' contract.

As Roberto has pointed out in his comment to my question, addMassSkeleton cannot be const if 'masses' is a member variable of mizer. If masses is a global object, the function could still be called const, but it might be misleading.

Comment: I think addMassSkeleton method shouldn't be const as it changes "masses" member.

Comment: You are correct, unless masses isn't owned by mizer.